# getting pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data while putting csv objects in send_key()

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

trying to extract links but getting error "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.", not getting how to solve this error.

tried using selenium chromedriver send_key, but fail to success.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    import csv
    import re
    import pandas as pd

    links = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\CIN_Name.xlsx',encoding='utf8',dtype=str,header=None,error_bad_lines=False)
    for i in range(0,5):
        link = links.iloc[i,0]

        url  = "https://www.knowyourgst.com/gst-number-search/by-name-pan/"

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get(url)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="gstnumber"]""").send_keys(str(link))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/input""").click()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
        driver.close()

        link = soup.find('div',{"id":"searchresult"}).find('a')
        print(link['href'])
```

want to extract link by putting objects in loop one by one by reading csv file column. please help me to solve this error.

Comment: You are extracting from excel file and provided  `pd.read_csv()` .It should be `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: thanks for correcting me.